# Selenium timed out error on waiting for page to load

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm aiming to extract a site that loads with javascript by using Selenium. I want to wait for the page to finish loading rather than setting a long-timer, however I'm getting the following error:

```
TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000102966269 __gxx_personality_v0 + 582729
1   chromedriver                        0x00000001028f1c33 __gxx_personality_v0 + 106003
2   chromedriver                        0x00000001024aee28 chromedriver + 171560
3   chromedriver                        0x00000001024e43d2 chromedriver + 390098
4   chromedriver                        0x00000001024e4591 chromedriver + 390545
5   chromedriver                        0x00000001025166b4 chromedriver + 595636
6   chromedriver                        0x00000001025019fd chromedriver + 510461
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000102514462 chromedriver + 586850
8   chromedriver                        0x0000000102501c23 chromedriver + 511011
9   chromedriver                        0x00000001024d775e chromedriver + 337758
10  chromedriver                        0x00000001024d8a95 chromedriver + 342677
11  chromedriver                        0x00000001029228ab __gxx_personality_v0 + 305803
12  chromedriver                        0x0000000102939863 __gxx_personality_v0 + 399939
13  chromedriver                        0x000000010293ec7f __gxx_personality_v0 + 421471
14  chromedriver                        0x000000010293abba __gxx_personality_v0 + 404890
15  chromedriver                        0x0000000102916e51 __gxx_personality_v0 + 258097
16  chromedriver                        0x0000000102956158 __gxx_personality_v0 + 516920
17  chromedriver                        0x00000001029562e1 __gxx_personality_v0 + 517313
18  chromedriver                        0x000000010296d6f8 __gxx_personality_v0 + 612568
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8034694f4 _pthread_start + 125
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80346500f thread_start + 15
```

I'm unsure what this means - I have also increased my timer but the issue still persists.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = {'Accounting_and_Finance': ['https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs/Degree-Accounting-and-Finance'],
             'Aeronautical_Engineering': ['https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs/Degree-Aeronautical-Engineering'],
             'Manufacturing_Engineering': ['https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs/Degree-Manufacturing-Engineering'],
             'Agriculture_and_Forestry': ['https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs/Degree-Agriculture-and-Forestry'],
             'Anatomy_and_Physiology': ['https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs/Degree-Anatomy-and-Physiology'],
             'Anthropology': ['https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs/Degree-Anthropology'],
             'Archaeology': ['https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs/Degree-Archaeology'],
             'Architecture': ['https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs/Degree-Architecture']}

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
for k, html in url.items():
    for stuff_in in html:
        driver.get(stuff_in)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#row")))
```

Comment: Are you running headless? If so, I suggest running with a visible browser (headful?) so that you can see what is happening. It might also help to use a debugger to step through the code so you can control when the request to load the page is made.

Comment: Which element are you trying to access? there is no element present like `div#row` on the provided url. Could you elaborate what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @KunduK I was waiting for the container with the jobs to load

Comment: You should try this then `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.row.job-results-row")))`

Comment: @KunduK That works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary has an extra curly brace at the beginning I suppose. Remove it and it should probably work good. I tried running the code post the changes, but I am simply denied access after hitting the url

[image: WebdriverWait at work]

[image: Hit the url]

[image: Permission Denied status]

Comment: The extra brace I missed only for the purpose of this example; I'm using a pandas dataframe. So, there's no access to the site, is that why it gets timed=out?

Comment: This is the traceback I get:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Private/stackoverflow/pythonProject/insta.py", line 27, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#row")))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: `

So I could say it is due to no access that it is timing out. Any other insights are welcome.